# How to unlock seatbelt during replacement

Tags: mazda, seat-belt

I’m trying to replace the seatbelt in a 1997 Mazda Demio that had a frayed belt. I removed the belt from a donor car, which was working fine when I removed it, but now that I go to install it the mechanism appears to have locked. I’ve also removed the frayed belt, which was functioning fine other than the fraying, and the same thing appears to have happened on that belt. It’s as if once the mechanism is no longer under tension it locks up, but there doesn’t appear to be anyway to release it.

Is there a way to release the mechanism again so the belt can be extended and installed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That seat belt has a weight activated lock. It locks the seat belt during high accelerations or decelerations.

You will be able to pull the belt out when that weight is in the at rest position. Its also possible you are one pawl into lock where it won’t release.

Try orienting the assembly into in car orientation. The thing uses gravity. When the weight is oriented down the pawls should release.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I’ve tried setting it in position and it still doesn’t unlock, although it does kinda feel like it’s set for acceleration (like you can pull it a centimetre or so and it still retracts). Is there a way to get it to unlock?

Comment: @JamiePatt be careful when replacing seatbelts some of them uses an explosive charge to tighten the belt if you are in an accident(it can be triggered if you pull too fast/hard at the belt)